# WHEN function condition not getting honoured in pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have been facing the following weird issue.

Below are some checks to support the facts.

```
df.filter((df.status == "pending") & ((F.col("col1").isNull()) | (F.col("col2").isNull()))).count() -> 0
df.filter((df.status == "pending") & ((F.col("col1").eqNullSafe(None)) | (F.col("col2").eqNullSafe(None)))).count() -> 0
df.filter((df.status == "pending") & ((isnan("col1")) | (isnan("col2")))).count() -> 0
df.filter((df.status == "pending") & ((F.col("col1") == None) | (F.col("col2") == None))).count() -> 0
```

Above 4 lines show that there is no NULL or None values present in col1 and col2 where status is pending.

Now, trying to calculate a column based on col1 and col2 with a UDF, where UDF has some conditions and one computation where col1 * col2 is getting retured.

```
df1 = df.withColumn("new_col", F.when(df.status == "pending", udf_func(df.col1, df.col2)).otherwise(F.lit(0.0)))
df1.show(2, False) -> does not work
```

Failing with error

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 377, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 372, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 248, in <lambda>
    func = lambda _, it: map(mapper, it)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/util.py", line 99, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in udf_func_name
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

If, I first filter the DF with the pending status and then apply the UDF then it works fine.

```
df2 = df.filter(df.status == "pending").withColumn("new_col",udf_func(df.col1, df.col2))
df1.show(2, False) -> works
```

Not able to understand what is happening here. Condition in WHEN is not getting honoured and UDF is getting called for all the records in DF and hence facing the error (my hypothesis). Is this correct expectation while working with WHEN and UDFs ?

Any pointers/help on the above is appreciated.

Spark Version: 2.4.8

Comment: you can check spark's plan with `.explain(True)` -- it might give some hints on how spark is executing the func. it might also be an issue within the `udf_func`.

Comment: UDFs do not support conditional expressions. You need to add the condition in your  function

Comment: thank you @blackbishop. Much appreciated for the help.